# Spring MVC - noHandlerFound / PageNotFound

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

i found a lot of similar questions asked about the problem i have, and tried a lot of solution, but it seems that none of them worked.

The most strange thing is that one of my associate can run the program so the code is not the problem.

The error which i get is when i run the app, i can't reach `welcomepage.html` and `hellopage.html`.

> déc. 20, 2016 9:42:37 AM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/SpringMVC/hellopage.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint"></context:component-scan>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
package com.javatpoint;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  

@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController {  

    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  

        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }  

}
```

**WelcomeWorldController.java**

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class WelcomeWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "WELCOME SPRING MVC";
        return new ModelAndView("welcomepage", "message", message);
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="hellopage.html">click</a>
|
<a href="welcomepage.html">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a maven project that i run with tomcat 7.0.73

There is the structure of the project directory

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmNBm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZWc4.png)

Comment: check your context path .right click on you server in eclipse and go to modules see the path for project .whether it is springMVC

Comment: the error is quite obvious , * No mapping found [/SpringMVC/hellopage.html] * . The controllers you posted are mapped in /welcome and /hello. Nothing in *.html.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated there is no problem with the code as it is running on your friend's system, I am assuming there is some problem with the configuration.

Please verify that the project name is proper in all the config files and in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

As you configured your controller (HelloWorldController) request mapping with @RequestMapping("/hello"), so your URL should be /SpringMVC/hello.html          (Not /SpringMVC/hellopage.html).
Also same for (WelcomeWorldController) request mapping.